# Most efficient data structure for holding list of forbidden pairs

Tags: ruby, data-structures, hash

I'm implementing a team allocation algorithm in Ruby and am to the point where I have to implement functionality where, when provided a list of pairs of IDs of students, those students should be grouped together.

What is the most efficient structure to implement that?

I was thinking of a Hash, where the key is the student ID and the value is array holding all the IDs of students a particular student cannot be grouped with.
For example, if the CSV file is has the following contents:

```
3,4
3,6
3,8
4,7
4,1
5,2
```

I want to get the following Hash:

```
{3=>[4,6,8], 4 =>[7,1], 5 =>[2]}
```

However, I cannot think of efficient way to populate the hash with information from the CSV file. The file has two values per row.
The most repeated action after that will be checking if a given ID exists in the lists of forbidden mates for a given student.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please see "[ask]" and the linked pages and "[MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)". We appreciate that you might be new, but we do expect evidence of the effort you've put into this. Where did you search? Why didn't it help? If it did, where is the code you wrote to test what you learned? If you didn't write code, why not? If you did, what is the minimal code that demonstrates the problem you encountered, along with the explanation of the problem, and the minimal input data and the expected result? Without that it's hard to help you.

Comment: Appreciate your help a lot, however, I don't think everybody is interested in the topic of my final year project, which I just happened to be writing in a language I haven't used before, especially when I'm asking something pretty general. 30 minutes after asking, I got absolutely helpful answer, according to which apparently its author understood what I was asking. Why adding information nobody cares about?
Also, is my question first world problem, that should explain my background research on the topic, while there are tons of questions like "How do I remove an item from an array?"

Comment: Also, I'll happily share with you the whole project report, when it is done in less than two weeks if you want :)
I'm also very very very curious what was wrong the last line saying thanks to everybody who spent time looking at the question and especially to the ones who answered?

Comment: SO isn't a message board or forum. It's more like an online reference book, and in reference books we don't use salutations, valedictions or signatures. "Hi", and "Thanks" are considered fluff; while they're polite social mechanisms, they don't further the question or answer, they merely take up space and, when taken to the extreme, detract severely from the content. https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/93989/153968 helps explain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
require 'CSV'

csv_string = %q(3,4
3,6
3,8
4,7
4,1
5,2 )

CSV.parse(csv_string, converters: :numeric)
   .group_by(&:first)
   .transform_values { |values| values.map(&:last) }
```

Comment: Neat! Thanks mate!

Comment: sure. see updated, as I show how to convert to integers if that's what you need

Comment: Updated to show with integers if you need, also removed `.compact` not needed.

Comment: Or the more direct version of this approach: `CSV.parse(csv_string, converters: :numeric).group_by(&:first).transform_values { |values| values.map(&:last) }` with the added benefit of them all being in one hash, not an array of hashes with 1 element

Comment: @SimpleLime thanks, great refactor updated. I knew there was a better way but didn't know about passing `converters: :numeric` .

Comment: [Typed Data Reading](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html#class-CSV-label-Typed+data+reading)  and the [Converters](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html#Converters) constant, and it's listed as an option to [`new`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html#method-c-new)

Comment: I just realised that this solution doesn't produce a Hash, it rather creates a list of single hashes, how do we change it so we get just one hash?

Comment: @АнтонПашов try it again, for me it produces a single hash. My original answer didn't but this was updated prior to your last comment.